# Quiz form submission format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created three models, "Survey", "Question", and "Answer". Survey has_many Questions which has_many Answers (and they all belong to the model above them).

I create a quiz using this form in the SurveyController edit action. In the `show` action of the SurveyController, I want to take the quiz I created and generate the quiz itself for the user to take. It submits to the create action of QuizResponses controller.

```
<%= form_for(:quiz_responses, url: quiz_responses_path) do |f| %>

<%= hidden_field_tag :name, @survey.name %>

<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<ul> 
<%= hidden_field_tag :question, question.content %>
<%= f.label question.content %>

<% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
<%= f.label answer.content %>
<%= f.radio_button(:user_answer, answer.content) %>

<% end %>

</ul>

<% end #@questions.each do %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end #form_for%>
```

But it shows up in a really ugly format. How do I change the form to make it look better (IE answer text with the checkbox?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is too broad, but here's a simple solution:

```
<%= form_for(:quiz_responses, url: quiz_responses_path) do |f| %>

  <%= hidden_field_tag :name, @survey.name %>

  <% @questions.each do |question| %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag :question, question.content %>

    <!-- question title -->
    <h3><%= f.label question.content %></h3>

    <!-- questions answers -->
    <ul>
      <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>

        <!-- use display:inline-block or float to make inline li -->
        <li>
          <%= f.label answer.content %>
          <%= f.radio_button(:user_answer, answer.content) %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>

  <% end %>

  <!-- submit -->
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

Comment: I get an error syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input '.freeze; end #form_for ^. Know why? EDIT: woops, nevermind!

Comment: Actually you just changed it with css right? I thought it was showing up wonky because I did something wrong in the form itself, but is my original form good?

Comment: I put the "question title" in `h3`, the question possible answers in `ul/li`, and the submit button in the `p` (because of the `p`'s default margin style). From there you can now style those elements with CSS as you like (you can add class to those elements). In your example the markup is not valid because you used the `ul` element without it's child elements - `li`.